# Зачем в Mongo Timestamp 2 даты?

Tags: mongodb

increment там для чего? И что это такое?
http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb-bson-timestamp.construct.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Цитируя описание BSON,](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/#timestamps)

> The BSON timestamp type is for internal MongoDB use. For most cases, in application development, you will want to use the BSON date type.

Этот тип данных предназначен для внутреннего использования в `mongodb` и обычно не должен использоваться извне.

Как сказано там же, в пределах одного инстанса `mongod` значение поля `timestamp` должно быть всегда уникальным. `increment` - постороннее порядковое число, не имеющее особого смысла, для создания уникальных идентификаторов в пределах одной секунды эпохи unix.

Повторюсь, использовать этот тип данных не надо. Используйте тип `Date` вместо него. К тому же в отличии от timestamp, Date 64-битный и не подвержен проблеме 2038 года, которая уже не в таком туманном будущем, как может казаться - уже меньше 22 лет осталось.